# Alternative methods other than time series to estimate weekly ATM Cash Demand for 1 and 1/2 years worth data

Tags: r, time-series, data-science

I have my data with the weekly demand on Cash Withdrawal for several ATMS for an year and half (2017 Jan - 2018 Jun). I want to be able to forecast the demand for subsequent weeks. I tried time series but it appears that the data is not sufficient to make a forecast (less than 2 years data).

Is there any other alternative method to estimate the weekly cash demand? (using R)

```
Date         ATM1        ATM2      ATM3 ......   ATMN
2017-01-02   50000      75000     120000         30000
2017-01-09   64000      70000      80000         50000
...
2018-06-25   70000      50000     100000         60000
```

There is no way of obtaining data older than the specified period. Any advice on the methodology to implement?

Comment: Maybe a curve may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough weekly data (and a year and a half should be enough) you can just try to build an [autoregressive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model).

Just choose a time window (say, 8 weeks - you can tune this as any other hyperparameter) and represent your training set as:

W1, W2 ... W8 ---> W9

W2, W3 ... W9 ---> W10

Once you have your training data in that format, you can treat it as a regression problem, and use any ML algorithm available (Decision Trees (including things like Random Forest/Gradient Boosting), Neural Networks, SVMs, Linear Regression ...).

And finally, for prediction you just need to provide the N weeks before the point in time you want to predict. Also note that if you have additional data (like, say, the average weekly temperature on the street), it is very easy to incorporate it into your training set, as additional weekly columns.

Comment: Thanks much! About the format you mentioned:
Did you mean- predict Week9 with the data from Week 1 to 8? and so on?

Comment: Exactly - that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data. If strong seasonality isn't present, you could try a simple linear regression using something like this:

```
cash <- c(10000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 70000, 90000)
month <- seq(1, length(data), 1)
fit <- lm(data ~ month)

summary(fit)

# Call:
#   lm(formula = data ~ month)
# 
# Residuals:
#   1       2       3       4       5       6 
# 3333.3 -2666.7  1333.3 -4666.7  -666.7  3333.3 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  -9333.3     3399.3  -2.746   0.0516 .  
# month        16000.0      872.9  18.330 5.21e-05 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 3651 on 4 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.9882,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9853 
# F-statistic:   336 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 5.211e-05
```

In the simple example above, we can see that each month we expect an increase of $16,000

Comment: Hi @user5783745 - Is there anything else that can work? I didn't find linear regression to work well on the data I have.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work well ? The R^2 is bad ? What about the Fisher and the p-sign?

Comment: I would be surprised there is no seasonality: the withdrawal should be higher at the end of the month, just after the payroll days.

Comment: @AlainD I was unable to use decompose() function as I do not have data for more than 2 years. I was however able to add a variable that flagged weeks having a US Federal Holiday. But I believe the time series (arima) did not capture it.

Comment: I am not talking about decompose() or other build-in function at this exploratory phase of the process. Just a graph and eye-stimate. Two year is enough to see (see!) if there are more activity by the end of the month. You should see some kind of wave of period 4-5. This period is *NOT* easily seen by a program because you do not have a round number of weeks in a month (4.34 to be exact). The human brain still has some superiority on AI at least for a decade or so...